# Error reading configuration file in java

Tags: java, file, configuration

I am reading a text file in java but I get the following error message

"Error reading configuration file. Make sure its correct path is specified."

I have supplied the correct file path but donot know from where error is coming.

package wordsensefinder;

```
import in.ac.iitb.cfilt.jhwnl.JHWNL;
import in.ac.iitb.cfilt.jhwnl.JHWNLException;
import in.ac.iitb.cfilt.jhwnl.data.IndexWord;
import in.ac.iitb.cfilt.jhwnl.data.IndexWordSet;
import in.ac.iitb.cfilt.jhwnl.data.Pointer;
import in.ac.iitb.cfilt.jhwnl.data.PointerType;
import in.ac.iitb.cfilt.jhwnl.data.Synset;
import in.ac.iitb.cfilt.jhwnl.data.POS;
import in.ac.iitb.cfilt.jhwnl.dictionary.Dictionary;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;


public class Examples {

static void demonstration() {

    BufferedReader inputWordsFile = null;
    try {
        inputWordsFile = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (new FileInputStream ("inputwords.txt"), "UTF8"));
    } catch( FileNotFoundException e){
        System.err.println("Error opening input words file.");
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        System.err.println("UTF-8 encoding is not supported.");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    JHWNL.initialize();

    String inputLine;
    long[] synsetOffsets;

    try {
        while((inputLine = inputWordsFile.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println("\n" + inputLine);
            //   Look up the word for all POS tags
            IndexWordSet demoIWSet = Dictionary.getInstance().lookupAllIndexWords(inputLine.trim());                
            //   Note: Use lookupAllMorphedIndexWords() to look up morphed form of the input word for all POS tags              
            IndexWord[] demoIndexWord = new IndexWord[demoIWSet.size()];
            demoIndexWord  = demoIWSet.getIndexWordArray();
            for ( int i = 0;i < demoIndexWord.length;i++ ) {
                int size = demoIndexWord[i].getSenseCount();
                System.out.println("Sense Count is " + size);   
                synsetOffsets = demoIndexWord[i].getSynsetOffsets();
                for ( int k = 0 ;k < size; k++ ) {
                    System.out.println("Offsets[" + k +"] " + synsetOffsets[k]);    
                }

                Synset[] synsetArray = demoIndexWord[i].getSenses(); 
                for ( int k = 0;k < size;k++ ) {
                    System.out.println("Synset [" + k +"] "+ synsetArray[k]);
                    System.out.println("Synset POS: " + synsetArray[k].getPOS());
                    Pointer[] pointers = synsetArray[k].getPointers();
                    System.out.println("Synset Num Pointers:" + pointers.length);
                    for (int j = 0; j < pointers.length; j++) {                         
                        if(pointers[j].getType().equals(PointerType.ONTO_NODES)) {  // For ontology relation
                            System.out.println(pointers[j].getType() + " : "  + Dictionary.getInstance().getOntoSynset(pointers[j].getOntoPointer()).getOntoNodes());
                        } else {
                            System.out.println(pointers[j].getType() + " : "  + pointers[j].getTargetSynset());
                        }                           
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error in input/output.");           
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JHWNLException e) {
        System.err.println("Internal Error raised from API.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    demonstration();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code as text, not as an image. Post the exact message you get.

Comment: The file path seems to be wrong.

Comment: Can not see if this code where that message is printed.

Comment: you show the file path for a file with _inputWords_. But the error message which you show is different from your code. Can you provide the stack trace of the error? It seems that some other file is missing.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is in the same package as your java code then all you need to do is read the file this way

getClass().getResourceAsStream("inputwords.txt")